# help in sql count

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table with 2 columns (status and date) like the following:

```
status: U  T  U  U  L       
date:   12 14 15 16 17
```

Can I (using only 1 SQL statement) count the number of distinct values in the status?  That is:

- count(U)=3
- count(T)=1
- count(L)=2
- count(P)=0

Can I do this with 1 SQL query?

Note: I have static values in status. I can only have (U-T-L-P)

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Getting the zero for the P which does not appear is the tough part of this.  You'd need a list of the valid values in a table of some sort which you can then work with.

Comment: i am using sql server 2008.
anyway thx a lot. i solved the problem after reading the posts:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a row for every `status` and the count in the second column:

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(*) Cnt
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Status
```

So it would return

```
Status  Cnt
 U       3
 T       1
 L       1
```

for your example (in no defined order). Use `ORDER BY` if you want to sort the results.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp):

```
SELECT Status, Count(Status)
FROM table
GROUP BY Status
```

This will not return `P = 0` if `P` is not populated in the table. In your application logic you will need to check and if a certain status is not returned, it means there are no entries (i.e. 0).

SQL cannot query records that are not there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a query which groups on your status column, e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as StatusCount, Status
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Status
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the zero for the status P, you have to do some devious stuff using a table that lists all the possible statuses.

```
SELECT COUNT(A.Status), B.Status
  FROM AnonymousTable AS A RIGHT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT 'P' AS Status FROM Dual
        UNION
        SELECT 'U' AS Status FROM Dual
        UNION
        SELECT 'L' AS Status FROM Dual
        UNION
        SELECT 'T' AS Status FROM Dual
       ) AS B ON A.Status = B.Status
 GROUP BY B.Status;
```

The 4-way UNION is one way of generating a list of values; your DBMS may provide more compact alternatives.  I'm assuming that the table Dual contains just one row (as found in Oracle).

The COUNT(A.Status) counts the number of non-null values in A.Status.  The RIGHT OUTER JOIN lists the row from B with Status = 'P' and joins it with a single NULL for the A.Status, which the COUNT(A.Status) therefore counts as zero.  If you used COUNT(*), you'd get a 1 for the count.